# Quiz with radio buttons using PHP and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, yahoo, bing

**I am trying to make a Quiz with radio buttons, but i dont know how to post the answers after the buttons are clicked i have added some comments where i explain this at the end of the code.**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
echo "<b> QUIZZZ!!!!! </b> <br>";
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------<br>";
 $k=1;
 $filmat = array("Horror","Aksion","Komedi","Romance","Thriller","Fantazi");
for ($i=0; $i <=5 ; $i++) { 

    echo "$k) Do u like  {$filmat[$i]} movies?";// willl genearate questions from  1->6
    echo "<br>";
    echo"<input type='radio' id='butonYes$k'>Yes";// will generate buttons with  id from 1->6
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' id='butonNo$k'> No";$k++;
    echo "<br>";
}

echo "----------------------------------------------------------------<br>";
echo "the films u selected are: <br>";

// here i want some jquery or php code to print the question with which genere of movies are clicked 
//for exaple i want just to print
/*
Horror
Aksion
Fantazi
*/
// if there are the only ones that are cliked yes
//pls help
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you should be looking at to achieve this. Firstly you need wrap the input elements into a form tag. Then have the page check to see if there is POST data before displaying  the results. The radio input tag is best when it's grouped by its name attribute rather than have them all with unique ids.

```
<?php
    echo "<b> QUIZZZ!!!!! </b> <br>";
    echo "----------------------------------------------------------------<br>";
    echo "<form method='POST' action=''>";
    $k=1;
    $filmat = array("Horror","Aksion","Komedi","Romance","Thriller","Fantazi");
        for ($i=0; $i <=5 ; $i++) { 
            echo "$k) Do u like  {$filmat[$i]} movies?";// willl genearate questions from  1->6
            echo "<br>";
            echo"<input type='radio' name='{$filmat[$i]}' value='yes'>Yes";// will generate buttons with  id from 1->6
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<input type='radio' name='{$filmat[$i]}' value='no'> No";$k++;
            echo "<br>";
    }
    echo "<input type='submit'>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "----------------------------------------------------------------<br>";
    echo "the films u selected are: <br>";

    // do something with the results here
    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
        echo "<pre>;";
        print_r($_POST);
    }
?>
```

Comment: thank you i used the form and if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))

Comment: to print my answers i used  the code below:                                                     if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST)) {

 for ($i=1; $i <=6 ; $i++) { 
  # code...
 
 if (!empty($_POST["buton$i"])&&(($_POST["buton$i"])=="butonYes$i")) {
  echo "<em class='fo'>$i) {$filmat[$i-1]}</em>";
  echo "<br>";
 }
 elseif (!empty($_POST["buton$i"])&&(($_POST["buton$i"])=="butonNo$i")) {
  echo "";
 }
 else {
 echo "Ju lutem plotesoni pyetjen $i)  !";
 echo "<br>";
}